# Ionic slider - Read contents of an images folder

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Right now I am implementing a simple view using Ionic that includes a few images, and the code looks like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-slides pager>

<ion-slide style="background-color: white">
  <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  <img src="../../assets/img/animals/dog.jpg">
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide style="background-color: white">
  <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  <img src="../../assets/img/animals/horse.jpg">
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide style="background-color: white">
  <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  <img src="../../assets/img/animals/cat.jpg">
</ion-slide>
```

I am quite new to ionic and to angular in general, so I was wondering what would be the best approach to loop through the entire /img/animals folder, scan for .jpg files and create an `<ion-slide>` for each of the files. Since there are a lot of assets yet to come, and I don't think it'll be practical to add custom code for each of them every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your template iterate over an array:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides" style="background-color: white">
  <h2>{{ slide.title }}</h2>
  <img [src]="slide.url">
</ion-slide>
```

in your component, define this variable "slides":

```
class YouComponent {
  slides = [];
  someMethod() { }
}
```

somewhere inside your component, you can define it:

```
someMethod() {
  this.slides = [
    { title: 'Title 1', url: 'url1.jpg' },
    { title: 'Title 2', url: 'url2.jpg' },
    { title: 'Title 3', url: 'url3.jpg' }
  ]
}
```

this array that is sued to set the value from this.slides can be hard-coded in your component .ts file, can be read from a config file, can be retrieved from an API endpoint, etc... but the thing is that you decouple your template from the data.

Comment: So to do it 'dynamically' I need the this.slide[] array to be generated by looping the entire 'img' folder every time and create this array of objects? Since i'm really trying to avoid custom code regarding my assets - Because there are gonna be big data updates every time.

Comment: @GonrasKarols this is a choice that you will have to make: hard-code the array in the .ts file (or in an external .json file) or create some kind of routine with that read the content from assets/images folder (and I don't know if this is possible using client-side javascript). One approach is create automate the generation of a .json file, with a script (shell script, for example) that you run in development time that reads this folder and output a .json file.